# Web server within a WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, web-services, soap, webserver

**I have a WPF application** that is made exclusively for demonstration purposes about how to use a proprietary technology of my company (the app shows a map where tracked objects flying to and fro). Besides showing off our technology, the most important aspect of the demo app is simplicity. It has to be simple to try, simple to set up, simple to use otherwise prospective customers will dump us before they have seen anything. So the demo app **must be like checkout-compile-run.**

**However, I need to add a SOAP web service** for the purpose of demonstrating publish/subscribe functionality. But I want no web project, no configuration, no virtual directory, no WCF between web service and the app, or anything else that would make the setup more difficult than compile and run. I just want a single .EXE. **Is there a way to make my WPF app also become a simple web server that serves those web services?**

Again for the simplicity, it is important that:

- The web service implementation should not have virtual and/or physical directory, they should be available as .NET types compiled into my single EXE assembly (just as my web server).
- The web service objects should run in the same app domain as the WPF app, so they can freely talk to one another without remoting or WCF.

**I am limited to use .NET 3.5**

Comment: For sure you mean SOAP web service.  Not WCF service?

Comment: How about something like NancyFX https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy or ServiceStack http://www.servicestack.net/

Comment: Maybe HttpListener?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx

Comment: The first two things that occur to me are: 1. Fake out the network stuff for your demo, so your demo code just does method calls instead of WCF/SOAP; or 2. Put the demo server online (self-hosted or in the cloud) so users can check out the sample code and connect to the demo server right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: `System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost` class.

[Here is the MSDN sample code.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: But you specified without WCF or remoting. Did your requirements change?

Comment: I think I was inaccurate on using WCF term. I meant process-process communication under "WCF", which is obviously wrong. My point was having a single exe and making it xcopy deployable. Thanks for your effort and for pointing out the inconsistency.